# Back button history using Ajax without hash in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
    var idRetorno = null;
var link = null;


function handler() 
{
    if(this.readyState == this.DONE) {
    if(this.status == 200) 
    {
           $('#'+idRetorno).html(this.responseText);
           window.history.pushState('', '', link);
    }
  }
}

function link_ajax(linkp, idRetornop)
{
    idRetorno = idRetornop;
    link = linkp;

    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.onreadystatechange = handler;
    client.open("GET", link);
    client.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-Header', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    client.send();
}
```

Everything in my application calls the function link_ajax when a link is clicked, I tried to update the url with

```
window.history.pushState('', '', link);
```

but, the back button history does not work as expected, the pages are still the same.
I can't use hashes (#color:red exemple) in the Url because this is a requirement for the application. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used [onpopstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onpopstate) to detetct that the page state has changed?

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  alert("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
};
```

Comment: I put this code just below the code that I quoted, in fact, gives the message when I clicked the back button, but the content remains the same. If I put inside your window.location.reload function () solves, in a way, but as I identicaria if the event was generated from the click the back button and foward or not entering the URL, for example?